# Transform words into their basic form in Java

Tags: java, preprocessor, truncate, stemming

What is a good library to use in Java to transform words into their basic form? That is, if we have "go" "going" and "gone" on the input, I need to receive 3 times "go" on the output.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is 'stemming'. And you mean 3 times, not 2 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/).  It is licensed under BSD, so you should have no (legal) issues with using it.  Here is a [link to the source](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt).

Answer (score 0):

[Stanford Natural Language Processing](http://nlp.stanford.edu/)